# Find out max divisor of a positive integer

Tags: c

I need to find the biggest divisor of a positive integer and output it. Divisor should not be 1 or be equal to the integer itself. If it's a prime number the output should be "0". I have this code so far. However it doesn't work. It only works when I use "break" instead of "return 0" statement, but according to the task I should not use break :( How can I fix it? Thnx

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input, maxDiv;
    int div = 2;

    scanf("%d", &input);

    for ( ; div <= input/2; div += 1 ) {
        if ( input % div == 0 ) {
            maxDiv = input / div;
            return 0;
        } else {
            maxDiv = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", maxDiv);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to avoid `break`, well, there's still `goto`. You can also just change the variable controlling the loop condition.

Comment: Add the last printf before the first return?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using break. It is part of the language and was designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @user2992672: are you sure your code outputs max divisor? I think it outputs first divisor that divides input; a ok I see there is some trick involved

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite it this way

```
int main(){
    int input, maxDiv = 0;
    int div = 2;

    scanf("%d", &input);

    for(; !maxDiv; div++)
        if(!(input%div))
            maxDiv = input/div;

    printf("%d\n", ( maxDiv == 1 || input < 0 ? 0 : maxDiv ) );
    return 0;
}
```

It is an infinite loop that will exit as soon as `maxDiv != 0`. The complexity is `O(sqrt (n))` as there is always a divisor of n less than or equal to sqrt(n), so the code is bound to exit (even if input is negative).

I forgot, you have to handle the case where input is zero.

Comment: Don't forget to include <stdio.h> :)

Comment: @Olayinka. it works with regular integers, but with prime numbers it somehow outputs 1 instead of 0 :(

Comment: @user2992672 You can easily tweak the code to suit prime numbers but i've edited it to also handle negative inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can declare a flag?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input, maxDiv;
    int div = 2;
    char found = 0;

    scanf("%d", &input);

    for ( ; div <= input/2 && !found ; div += 1 ) {
        if ( input % div == 0 ) {
            maxDiv = input / div;
            found = 1;
        } else {
            maxDiv = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", maxDiv);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the loop when you reach `sqrt(input)`... it's not that difficult to find a perfectly good integer sqrt function.

There's not a lot of point dividing by all the even numbers after 2.  In fact there's not a lot of point dividing by anything except the primes.  It's not hard to find the primes up to `sqrt(INT_MAX)` (46340, for 32-bit integer)... there are tables of primes freely available if you don't want to run a quick sieve to generate same.

And the loop...

```
  maxdiv = 0 ;
  i = 0 ;
  sq = isqrt(input) ;
  while ((maxdiv == 0) && (prime[i] < sq))
    {
       if ((input % prime[i]) == 0)
         maxdiv = input / prime[i] ;
       i += 1 ;
     } ;
```

assuming a suitable integer sqrt function and a table of primes... as discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for the largest divisor, is there a reason you're not looping backward to 2? If there isn't, then there should be no need for a break statement or any special logic to exit the loop as you should keep looping until `div` is greater than `input / 2`, testing every value until you find the largest divisor.

```
maxDiv = -1;
for (div = input / 2;
     div >= 2 && maxDiv == -1;
     --div)
  {
    if (input % div == 0)
      maxDiv = div;
  }

maxDiv += (maxDiv == -1);

printf ("%d\n", maxDiv);
```

I added the extra condition of `maxDiv` being -1, which is like adding a conditional `break` statement. If it is still -1 by the end of the loop, then it becomes 0 because `maxDiv += 1` is like writing `maxDiv = -1 + 1`, which is 0.

Without any jump statement such as `break`, this sort of test is what you must do.

Also, regarding your code, if I input 40, the `if` statement will be triggered when `div` is 2, and the program will end. If the `return 0` is changed to a `break`, `maxDiv` will be 2, not 20. Looping backward will find 20 since 40/2=20, and 40%20==0.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote *D* to the max divisor of a given composite number *N > 1*.
Then, obviously, the number *d = N / D* is the min non-trivial divisor of *N*.
If *d* would not a primer number, then *d* would have a non-trivial divisor *p < d*.
By transitivity, this implies that *p* is a divisor of *N*, but this fact would contradict the fact that *d* is the min divisor of *N*, since *p < d*.

- So, *d* must be a prime number.

In particular, it is enouth to search over those numbers which are less than *sqrt(N)*, since, if *p* is a prime number greater than *sqrt(N)* which divies *N*, then *N / p <= sqrt(N)* (if not, *p * (N / p) > sqrt(N)*sqrt(N) == N*, wich is absurd).

This shows that it's enough to do the search the least divisor *d* of *N* just within the range of primer numbers from 2 to `sqrt(N)`.

For efficiency, the value *sqrt(N)* must be computed just once before the loop.
Moreover, it is enough a rough approximation of *sqrt(N)*, so we can write:

```
   #include <math.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
      int N;
      scanf("%d",&N);

      // First, we discard the case in that N is trivial
      // 1 is not prime, but indivisible. 
      // Change this return if your want.
      if (N == 1)
         return 0;
      // Secondly, we discard the case in that N is even.
      if (N % 2 == 0)
         return N / 2; 

      // Now, the least prime divisor of N is odd.
      // So, we increment the counter by 2 in the loop, by starting in 3.

      float sqrtN = fsqrt(N); // square root of N in float precision.
      for(d = 3; d <= sqrtN; d += 2)
         if (N % d == 0)
            return N/d;

      // If the loop has reached its end normally, 
      // it means that N is prime.

      return 0;
   }
```

I think that the problem is not well stated, since I consider that a better flag to signalize that *N* is prime would be a returned value of 1.

There are more efficient algorithms to determine primality, but they are beyond the scope of the present question.